# How can I subscribe to a websocket user queue from a Python client?

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, websocket

I want to create a service where a Python client can subscribe to a user queue on a websocket served by spring-boot. There are several resources available online, however these all focus on

- connecting with a **JavaScript** client (SockJS) client instead of a **Python** client, or
- connecting to a **topic** instead of a **user queue**.

I found the following resources:

- Spring-boot 2.0.2 allows to create a simple websocket server. The article shows how to publish to a topic (`@SendTo` annotation). [Spring Websockets](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)
- This article from Baeldung describes how to create a subscription to a user queue (`@SendToUser` annotation). [Baeldung Websockets](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-sendtouser)

I found websocket-client and websockets as active recent Python modules, however the manuals do not explain on subscribing to user queues.

- Python websocket-client [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) [Website](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)
- Python websockets [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) [Website](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

Is there an example how to connect to a user queue from a Python client?

**Example websocket server**

Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class ClientWebsocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(@NotNull MessageBrokerRegistry aMessageBrokerRegistry)
    {
        aMessageBrokerRegistry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/user");
        aMessageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        aMessageBrokerRegistry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(@NotNull StompEndpointRegistry aStompEndpointRegistry)
    {
        aStompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SubscriptionController
{
    @NotNull
    @MessageMapping("/subscribe")
    @SendToUser("/queue/reply")
    public ReplyMessage processSubscribeFromClient(
        @Payload Object object,
        Principal principal)
    {
        return new ReplyMessage("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Message:

```
class ReplyMessage
{
    @Nullable private String content;

    public ReplyMessage()
    {

    }

    public ReplyMessage(@Nullable String content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }
}
```